# Why did Chandler Bing get into the advertisement field?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, friends

Chandler Bing was working with a firm and then he changes his job.
Why did [Chandler Bing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandler_Bing) gets into advertisement field in [Friends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends)?

Comment: It's explicit in the episode: Chandler literally stops at the first idea offered by Monica, thinks it will be a fit, meets with Monica's friend, and gets an internship.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of monica, as explained here

> On Christmas Day, Chandler quits his job so that he can fly home to
>   New York to be with Monica. Monica helps Chandler secure a job in
>   advertising through an old college friend of hers. Much to Chandler's
>   dismay, the job is as an intern, which leaves him in the awkward
>   position of working alongside people who are significantly younger
>   than he. However, his more mature approach eventually pays off for him
>   compared to the other interns, and he secures a full-time job in the
>   business as a junior copywriter when he only expected to receive an
>   assistant position. The company concluded that he would be better
>   suited for a more senior role. ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandler_Bing))

Comment: Why he chooses only advertisement and not other jobs? Was that a secure job?

Comment: Advertisement was the first job alphabetically.

Comment: @LoïcWolff: hehehehe. Chandler can do anything :P

Comment: and I think its because Chandler just hated his job. He always wanted to get out from it and do something else. So in that episode when he quits when it made him go away on x-mas eve, He decided to give his wishes a chance. He quits and found another field with help from Monica